# Birthday problem, the hard way(not using 1-unfavourable outcomes).

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

How would you go about calculating the chance of two people having the same birthday in a room of 3 people and a year consisting of 365 days?

Comment: "The hard way" is basically using inclusion exclusion principle, which is basically not realizing that it equals the "easy way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3$ main cases:

- person 1 = person 2,
- person 2 = person 3, and
- person 1 = person 3.

Each case has a $365^2$ number of possibilities and they are independent so you add them not multiply. However we end up adding the special case of person 1 = person 2 = person 3 twice more than intended so you must subtract it out.

$$365\cdot 365\cdot 3=399675$$

$$399675-2\cdot 365=398945$$

$$398945/(365^3)=0.008204$$

Comment: 3 main cases, person 1 = person 2, person 2 = person 3 and
person 1 = person 3. Each case has a 365^2 number of possibilities and they are independent so you add them not multiply. However we end up adding the special case of person 1 = person 2 = person 3 twice more than intended so you must subtract it out

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$P(A)=1-\frac{_{365}P_n}{365^n}$$ in this case $n=3$, see [Birthday Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: Without using that formula, I'm guessing you would have to split it into cases, person 1 and person 2 share the same birthday, person 2 and person 3 share the same birthday, person 1 and person 3 share the same birthday and the last case person 1 person 2 and person 3 all have the same birthday

Comment: **Think in the complement**; Note that the probability, that   the 3 persons not have same birthday, is equivalent,  $$\frac{365\cdot364\cdot363}{365\cdot365\cdot365}$$